# Can I measure the accuracy of a range of quantiles in my forecast distribution?

Tags: r, forecasting, accuracy, scoring-rules

I am forecasting items and measuring the point forecast and distribution accuracy of numerous different models against actuals. To measure distribution accuracy I am using the continuous-ranked probability score (CRPS.)

If I only desire to know how part of my forecast distribution performed (all parts of the distribution above the median forecast), is there a way to do this?

Comment: Parts of this question are obscure.  Could you explain what you mean by "CRPS"?  What do you mean by "distribution accuracy ... about the 50th percentile"?

Comment: Use quantile scores and average over the parts of the distribution you're interested in. See https://otexts.com/fpp3/distaccuracy.html for further explanation.

Comment: @whuber: The CRPS is the *Continuous Ranked Probability Score*, a very common proper scoring rule for numerical density forecasts.

Comment: @RobHyndman thank you for sharing. This textbook is very useful.

Comment: @RobHyndman if I am interested in the upper bound of the quantile range (51st - 99th), is it enough to take the average of the quantile score for those specific probs? I am using the fabletools::quantile_score function for each point.

Comment: @bonddr. Yes, that's it. This is equivalent to using a weighted CRPS where the weight is 0 before 0.5 and 1 afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You can use quantile weighting for your Continuous Ranked Probability Score (CRPS). [Gneiting & Ranjan, "Comparing Density Forecasts Using Threshold- and Quantile-Weighted Scoring Rules", *Journal of Business & Economic Statistics* (2011)](https://doi.org/10.1198/jbes.2010.08110) is precisely what you need.

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: @Stephan Kolassa are you aware of the codes for Quantile Weighted Scoreing Rules in R or MATLAB?

Comment: @Rollo99: unfortunately, I don't know of any implementations as such, but if I remember correctly, the formulas in Gneiting & Ranjan are not that hard. For R, you might find something in the [`scoringRules`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=scoringRules) or the [`scoringutils`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=scoringutils) packages (which I personally haven't used, so I can't be any more helpful; I just found them by [searching on CRAN for "Gneiting"](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffsb&q=gneiting+site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fcran.r-project.org)), Good luck!

Comment: thanks a lot for answering and for your help!